# ImageMagick equivalent to Box-shadow CSS property

Tags: php, css, imagemagick

I want to imitate the box-shadow CSS property in ImageMagick for an image. I want it to behave exactly the same. Is there any function or equivalent mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
  /* Read the image into the object */
  $im = new Imagick( 'a.jpg' );
  $im->setImageFormat("png");

  /* Make the image a little smaller, maintain aspect ratio */
  $im->thumbnailImage( 200, null );

  /* Clone the current object */
  $shadow = $im->clone();

  /* Set image background color to black (this is the color of the shadow) */
  $shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) );

  /* Create the shadow */
  $shadow->shadowImage( 80, 3, 5, 5 );

  /* Imagick::shadowImage only creates the shadow. That is why the original image is composited over it */
  $shadow->compositeImage( $im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 );

 /* Display the image */
 header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
 echo $shadow;
?>
```

[also you can see imagemagick for bash script](http://blog.bemoko.com/2009/07/01/add-shadow-and-border-to-images-with-imagemagick/)

Comment: I actually wanted a mapping of the following to this answer. Thanks a lot for your help. :-)

box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [Imagick::shadowImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.shadowimage.php) (-shadow switch for CLI)